# Is there a way to configure what is displayed in the case feed?

Tags: case, casefeed

I have set up case feed for my org, however, emails show up as lengthly messages, is there a way to shorten what is displayed?

Answer (score -1):

The way we do this is by using Workflow rules (under App Setup | Create | Workflow & Approvals) to specify when we want a particular email template to be used.

The condition for the workflow can be e.g. a case with a particular record type has been created and for a particular account. Then associate an immediate action of Email Alert, and tie that to an email template which only contains the relevant information.

We use this with account teams to ensure that all the relevant people are copied, and also have additional email addresses included for things like a generic support email list.

We have different email templates for various events such as new case creation, case comment addition, escalation rules for cases which have been untouched for a certain amount of time, etc. We ensure that only the relevant information is included in the email template for each of these events.